# What is the expected length of the longest increasing subsequence of a random permutation of the first n natural numbers?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

What is the average length of the longest increasing subsequence of a random permutation of the first n natural numbers?

Comment: IIRC, this is asymptotic as $2\sqrt{n}$. Don't think there is a known closed form.

Comment: @Macavity do you know a reference for this fact ?

Comment: @ewanDelanoy search for aldous & diaconis, 1995 Don't have the exact reference handy.

Comment: Ok - [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01204214) it is.