# Difficult question about asymptotic notations and permutations

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics

Let $ S_n$ be all the permutations on $ [n]$. For every $ \sigma \in S_n $ let $L( \sigma)$ be the length of the longest increasing sub-series of the series: $ (\sigma(1),\sigma(2),...,\sigma(n))$.

I need to prove that $$ \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} L(\sigma) = \Omega(n^{n+1}e^{-n})$$

First of all, by using Stirling it will be enough to prove that $ \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} L(\sigma) = \Omega((n!)\sqrt n)$.

I tried about comparing it to the same sum but only with permutations that kept their order until k for $ 1 \le k \le n$ but the exponent didn't go well.

I tried also to use only permutations with fixed points (as those points are an increasing sub-series) but I wasn't sure how to do that.

Comment: So, equivalently, you need to prove that the *expected* length of the longest increasing subsequence is $\Omega(\sqrt{n})$ (when you draw a permutation uniformly at random). Do you see why?

Comment: (also, you want to use the word "sequence," not "series")

Comment: See e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622315/expected-length-of-longest-increasing-subsequence-of-a-random-sequence), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347072/what-is-the-expected-length-of-the-longest-increasing-subsequence-of-a-random-pe), or the reference from the corresponding [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence#Length_bounds). The answer is actually $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$, and even more precisely $2\sqrt{n}+o(\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: Is it a known fact that I can just use? Because I don't exactly understand the proof.

Comment: Without looking too much in detail, it seems "highly non-trivial" (I'd say) to get the exact asymptotics, but there may be a more elementary proof since you only want an $\Omega(\sqrt{n})$ bound.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to prove the lower bound? I thought about Erdos-Szekeres as the series is with length of $(\sqrt n +1)(\sqrt n -1) + 1 = n$ so there is and increasing sub sequence with the length of $\sqrt n$ or a decreasing one.

Comment: Added an answer. But again: we are dealing with *sequences*, not *series*. If you use the wrong word, searching the literature will be a heck of a lot harder.

Answer (score 1):

***Disclaimer***: this is strongly inspired by and follows the exposition of [1], specifically Section 1.3. I strongly suggest you read this book if you are interested in the topic.

Recall the [Erdős—Szekeres theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Szekeres_theorem):

> **Theorem.** (Erdős—Szekeres)  For any integers $r, s\geq 0$, every sequence of length at least $(r - 1)(s - 1) + 1$ contains a monotonically increasing subsequence of length $r$ or a monotonically decreasing subsequence of length $s$.

In particular, for any $r,s\geq 1$ such that $n> rs$, any permutation $\sigma\in\mathcal{S}_n$ satisfies $L(\sigma) \geq r$ or $D(\sigma)\geq r$ (where $D(\sigma)$ is the length of the longest decreasing subsequence); or, equivalently, 
$$
\forall \sigma\in\mathcal{S}_n,\quad L(\sigma)D(\sigma) > n \tag{1}
$$

By symmetry, the distributions of $L(\sigma)$ and $D(\sigma)$ when $\sigma$ is chosen uniformly at random from $\mathcal{S}_n$ are the same, and thus $\mathbb{E}_\sigma[L(\sigma)]=\mathbb{E}_\sigma[D(\sigma)]$. Therefore, we can write
$$
\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\sigma\in\mathcal{S}_n} L(\sigma)=\mathbb{E}_\sigma[L(\sigma)] = \frac{\mathbb{E}_\sigma[L(\sigma)]+\mathbb{E}_\sigma[D(\sigma)]}{2}
= \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\sigma\in\mathcal{S}_n} \frac{L(\sigma)+D(\sigma)}{2}\tag{2}
$$
By the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means), we get
$$
\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\sigma\in\mathcal{S}_n} \frac{L(\sigma)+D(\sigma)}{2}
\geq \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\sigma\in\mathcal{S}_n} \sqrt{L(\sigma)D(\sigma)} \tag{3}
$$
and, combining (1), (2), and (3), we obtain that for all $n\geq 1$,
$$
\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\sigma\in\mathcal{S}_n} L(\sigma) \geq \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\sigma\in\mathcal{S}_n} \sqrt{L(\sigma)D(\sigma)} \geq \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\sigma\in\mathcal{S}_n} \sqrt{n}
$$
i.e. $\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\sigma\in\mathcal{S}_n} L(\sigma) \geq \sqrt{n}$. $~~~\square$

---

[1] Romik, Dan. *The surprising mathematics of longest increasing subsequences.* Institute of Mathematical Statistics Textbooks. Cambridge University Press, New York, 2015. xi+353 pp. ISBN: 978-1-107-42882-9; 978-1-107-07583-2 *Available freely on [the author's website](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~romik/book/).*